How to calculate magnitude for a filter to specific dB level?
I'm using fir2 function (and then filter with basic settings filter(fir2,1,audio) ) to filter audio files to specific values in each spectrum band. I have two sets of dB values:

the original spectrum of a file
the final spectrum I want the file to be

I've tried taking the difference between the two levels and un"log" it like that:
20^(FdB SPL - OdB SPL/20)

FdB - final level
OdB - original level

For example for a 125Hz band filter magnitude would be 20^(38-35/20) = 1.995
Then I would take these values and use them as magnitude for the fir2. I'm using 50nth order. It didn't seem to work properly, or it worked with various accuracy in different files. I'm using Artemis to calculate all the dB values with the function "1/n Octave Spectrum (FFT) (4096; 50%)". I'm using wav format for files. I probably messed something simple, like about the formula, but at this point I'd rather look like a dummy for not knowing something trivial instead of brute forcing it.
[audio,fs] = audioread(append(filename,".wav")) ;

f = [0  0.0004535147392 0.000566893424  0.0007256235828 0.0009070294785 0.001133786848  0.001428571429  0.001814058957  0.002267573696  0.002857142857  0.003628117914  0.004535147392  0.00566893424   0.007256235828  0.009070294785  0.01133786848   0.01428571429   0.01814058957   0.02267573696   0.02857142857   0.03628117914   0.04535147392   0.0566893424    0.07256235828   0.09070294785   0.1133786848    0.1428571429    0.1814058957    0.2267573696    0.2857142857    0.3628117914    0.4535147392    0.566893424 0.7256235828    0.9070294785    1];

m = [1  0.88180561540975    0.881805363482077   0.835826382716575   0.776642454832629   0.759436720529334   0.653244752807778   0.745167995891424   0.850117073913788   0.98912260419711    0.960201464902893   0.923199850846219   1.13897797703032    0.874874253414851   1.13953780367958    1.28584396648708    0.67694058247949    0.785826825740988   1.00665129584544    1.38588097381939    1.59663824625406    1.46013949870038    1.55967029805846    1.57082839521638    1.96165693766572    1.74722265683908    1.77693364984782    1.29579584587398    1.58136046978984    1.69990075644448    1.42024073863697    1.91114522246185    1.55168355673292    1.00086374398705    1.0301145684381 1];

b = fir2(50, f, m6);
A = 1;
Y = filter (b, A, audio);

amp = 0.06309573445
Y_new=Y*amp/rms(Y);

newname = append("f_","_",filename,".wav");
audiowrite (newname, Y_new, fs,'BitsPerSample',32);


As this is rather a signal processing question than a programming question I recommend to ask it at DSP.se

@Irreducible if you write the [dsp.se] SE in a comment, it shows up as "the [dsp.se] SE"
